# Java - see if input contains only numbers to the left of the operator

Tags: java, operators, calculator

I have a problem I can't seem to solve.
I want a piece of code only to run when the input only has numbers on the left side of the operator.
For example:
If the input is 100+, then the code should run.

But also if the input is 100-, 100*, 100/, 100^ etc.

I also want to be able to parse expressions like -100*50.

I'm sorry if the question isn't clear.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Is that necessary? I mean I just want a way to know if right side of operator is empty.

Comment: Yes it is necessary. We don't just write code for people. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not asking you to write code, I'm asking for a way. My code wouldn't change anything really.

Comment: You actually wrote "_I want a piece of code_", so you are indeed asking for it.

Comment: ok, you can begin [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @MarceloVinícius Did not mean for anyone here to write that piece of code. I meant I need help towards getting it.

Comment: @alias_boubou Thank you! Just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method uses a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that matches a line that starts with an optional `-` sign, an optinal space, then one or more numbers, an optional space, an operator (in this case, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` or `^`)m an optinal space, an optional `-` sign, an optinal space, then one or more numbers and finally, optional line endings.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\-?\\s?\\d+\\s?[\\+\\-*\\/\\^]\\s?\\-?\\s?\\d+\\r?\\n?$");
    System.out.println(p.matcher("123+").matches()); // outputs "true"
    System.out.println(p.matcher("123").matches()); // outputs "false"
    System.out.println(p.matcher("- 123123 *").matches()); // outputs "true"
    System.out.println(p.matcher("- 9843 * 23409").matches()); // outputs "true"
}
```

You can also [try it online](http://rubular.com/r/skHtpV62oZ) and provide your own input.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have some idea on how to let the numbers be negative also?
When I use this, it doesn't allow 10*-2 to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Another problem, I want the user to able to use spaces.

Comment: Changed my answer to allow negative numbers and a single space before and/or after the number.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm afraid you might've misunderstood the question.
I want to be able to put in 10+10, and that should be true. but also -10 + 10 etc. Could you update with that? 
I haven't learned how to use regular expressions yet.

Comment: Regex is an awesome tool, widely used by programmers. You might want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/learning-regular-expressions-for-beginners-the-basics/), where the author explains the basic concepts in a very intuitive way. Also, do not forget to upvote the answer if you think it could help other users in SO.

Comment: Thank you! I did upvote it.
I regret not learning about this before I started creating my calculator. It's far too complicated for what it's worth. If I would've known about regex before, it would have made everything much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think using of regular expression will be best in your case. You can write something like:

```
    String input = "100a^atcs";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+[\\+\\-\\*\\^].*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.matches())
    {
        //do code...
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code. The problem is that the code still ran even if for example, the input was 100+100. I want it only to run if the input doesn't have any numbers on the right side of the operator.

Comment: Nevermind! Played around with it and now it works. Thank you!